# Periodically saving a HashMap read out of a file

Tags: java, hashmap, filewriter

Alright everyone, I'm still in the process of self-teaching about writing server-side apps, and I'm working on a rough draft for an iOS app I have planned.

What I intend to do is have the app submit and request values to and from basically what amounts to be a `HashMap`of different keys and values, the exact behavior of which isn't necessary to explain.

Obviously, to maintain the stored server data across running instances of the app (i.e. restarts, adding more machines, etc.), I intend to use a `FileWriter` to save the `HashMap` to a file. Idea being, when the server application is first run, it pulls the saved `HashMap` into a instance for "working storage".

Do any of you have ideas on how to implement a setup that would periodically (every 1 to 10 seconds, suppose) save the file to make the "working example" and file synchronized (to prevent against loss of data due to power outage, program failure, act of God, etc.).

I looked up the reference for `FileWriter` and couldn't see anything listed. I'd definitely prefer to use a method more sophisticated than overwriting, destroying and reopening a file every second.

Word to the wary - I'm a *bit* new to Java. I can hold my own in the core language, but I don't have a massive inbuilt memory of all the different classes and interfaces that exist. A detailed description will make me even more happy.

Comment: Why don't you use a database?

Comment: _to prevent against loss of data due to power outage, program failure_ an ACID database is what you need. Plus, you don't really need the whole HashMap in memory do you?

Comment: @JBNizet Because this so far is a stretch for me. Right now I'm writing a rough draft of the app that is far from what will become final specification when I actually have the target iOS app and hardware set up. Right now while I'm still getting server-side figured out properly I'd prefer to keep things in more of an intuitive realm, and databases are far from it at this point.

Comment: Just wondering, if this is going to be an iOS app why are you working on this in Java?

Comment: @okiharaherbst Again, databases aren't something I've worked with before. In these initial stages I'd like to use something more intuitive, and file I/O certainly qualifies.

Comment: @user3580294 because _this isn't the app_. It's the server-side application that services the app I'm going to write.

Comment: If you're going to have multiple instances of the app reading and writing to the same file via a FileWriter, then I would use a singleton that has access to the file (and maybe even caches it) and have all instances go via this Singleton when interacting with the file. This should allow you to have some fun locking code too. In case Singletons aren't something you've come across, [here's the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) but there are loads of examples around the net.

Comment: @blasthash Ah that makes sense, my bad for the understanding

Comment: @DanTemple To make sure we're on the same page, there will be a single instance of the server app that can handle multiple concurrent connections. But the only file I/O for `FileWriter` will be singularly via the server application.

Comment: Yep, I maybe thought about it incorrectly, but I still think the singleton pattern applies here. If you've got a single *true* HashMap to be saved to a single file, then the multiple connections trying to access it should go via a Singleton class.

Comment: @DanTemple I'll definitely give it all a look. At any rate, the code I'm writing today will undergo many revisions and tests before I trust it with servicing user data.

Comment: @blasthash This is certainly no excuse (and a little odd). It appears to me that both you and this code would greatly benefit from integrating a simple, embedded database (see h2, hsqldb or SQLite). Believe me, there's no way for you to avoid learning databases and their uses in Java (or any other general purpose language). It's 100% worth the effort.

Comment: @okiharaherbst Be what it is, it's outside of the bounds of this question, and I'm not concerned with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use FileWriter unless you are only writing text.

Without more information I would suggest using XMLEncoder.  This has the advantage over binary formats that you can read and even modify the contents.  If you don't like XML, I suggest using YAML e.g. snakeyaml and this has a much nicer format.

You would have to lock access to the HashMap to avoid corruption.  I also suggest writing to a new file and only deleting the old file when you have written successfully.  This avoids loss data in the event of a failure while writing.

Comment: Ideally, the `HashMap` would consist of only ASCII strings. That being said, I like the idea of storage in XML format due to it being more "standard" than a variable-format text file. Would a way to carry out the new file be to create a new file name (say, append `-1`), write the new file, delete the old one and rename it?

Comment: @blasthash That is how I do it (except with a `.tmp` or `.deleteme` extension) I think dumping to XML is the simplest to start with.  The reverse is XMLDecoder.  Don't forget to use BufferedReader and writers

Comment: How would I work a `BufferedReader` on a `HashMap`? I must admit I haven't seen an instance buffering HashMaps.

Comment: You use `new XMLDecoder(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)))`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is have the autosaving mechanism live in a different thread that wakes up periodically and writes the `HashMap` using the `FileWriter`. One way you could do this is by creating an inner class that extends `Runnable` and has an instance variable that points to the `HashMap` that you want to write.

So maybe something like this:

```
class AutoSaver implements Runnable {
    private final HashMap<?, ?> mapToSave;
    private final FileWriter writer;
    public AutoSaver(HashMap<?, ?> mapToSave) {
        this.mapToSave = mapToSave;
        // initialize FileWriter
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // write HashMap
        Thread.sleep(interval);
    }
}
```

And then to start it up:

```
new Thread(new AutoSaver(mapToSave)).start();
```

You do have to be careful with this though, because with multiple threads accessing the same object you'll now have to deal with concurrency issues. One way to fix this would be to use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of plain `HashMap`.

Comment: Is `ConcurrentHashMap` the same, for the most part, as `HashMap`, just with concurrency considerations?

Comment: If memory serves, it's nearly a drop-in replacement, except that you can't use `null` as a key or value.